# Python: Looping over multiple subdirectories to find files containing a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, subdirectory

I have the code to evaluate all the files in a directory and list the files containing the specified string.

What I need to do is to have this loop over multiple sub-directories.

I've tried using os.walk but without success.

Appreciate any assistance.
This is my original query:

```
import os
path = input('Directory Path:  ')
directory = os.listdir(path)
searchstring1 = input('Search String:  ')
for fname in directory:
    if os.path.isfile(path + os.sep + fname):
        f = open(path + os.sep + fname, 'r')
        if searchstring1 in f.read():
            print('found string in file %s' % fname)
        f.close()
```

This is what I thought would work:

```
import os
path = input('Directory Path:  ')
searchstring1 = input('Search String:  ')
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for fname in files:
        f = open(fname, 'r')
        if searchstring1 in f.read():
            print('found string in file %s' % fname)    
        f.close()
```

What's being missed here?

Comment: Show us how you were trying to use `os.walk()` please. Why didn't that work?

Comment: I've tried several iterations but here is what I thought was most promising: 

    path = input('Directory Path:  ')
    directory = os.listdir(path)
    searchstring1 = input('Search String:  ')

    for root, dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for fname in files:
                f = open(fname, 'r')
                if searchstring1 in f.read():
                    print('found string in file %s' % fname)

f.close()

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that. You don't need to also use `os.listdir()` when using `os.walk()`.

Comment: The `files` list consists of *just* the names in the given directory, so you'd want to use `os.path.join(root, fname)` when opening.

Comment: s.path.join(root, fname) worked.